# Function callback loop 2 times

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

```
def callback(channel):
    print("WARNING! FLAME DETECTED!!!\n")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    firebase.post("/Report/Location", alamat)
    firebase.post("/Report/Time", masa)
    lcd_string("  FIRE DETECTED  ",LCD_LINE_1)
    lcd_string(masa,LCD_LINE_2)
    print ("SUCCESSFULL REPORTED\n" +"Time : " + masa + "\nLocation : " + alamat)   


GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW

GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change



# infinite loop

while True:

    time.sleep(10)
    lcd_init()
```

Hello, can someone explain me why this code above loop the function 2 time. This is more confusing me when i removed

```
firebase.post("/Report/Location", alamat)
firebase.post("/Report/Time", masa)
```

the code doesn't loop the function.

Answer (score 0):

When the interpreter reads the exit() statement, as far as I know, it breaks out of your infinite  loop  and program execution terminates.

Comment: sorry for my overlooked on the exit() statement that should not exist there.. Edited for the correction